# I want to update the product quantity in the basket

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, cart

To update the quantity of products in the shopping cart
I use buttons. But I'm doing something wrong. Can you help?

### sepet.blade.php CODE

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-xs azalt"
      data-id="{{ $UrunCartItem->rowId }}" 
      data-adet="{{$UrunCartItem->qty-1}}">-</a>

   <span style="padding: 4px 12px">

   {{ $UrunCartItem->qty }}

   </span>

 <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-xs artir"
    data-id="{{ $UrunCartItem->rowId }}" 
    data-adet="{{$UrunCartItem->qty+1}}">+</a>
```

### Javascript CODE

```
 <script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $('.artir , .azalt').on('click' , function () {
                debugger;
                var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                var adet = $(this).attr('data-adet');
                $.ajax({
                    type:'PATCH',
                    url:'/sepet/guncelle/' + id ,
                    data : { adet: adet } ,
                    success: function () {
                        window.location.href='/sepet';
                    }}); }); });
    </script>
```

### Page All Code

http://notes.io/8kex

Comment: Check here https://jqueryui.com/spinner/

Answer (score 1):

At first, add `event.preventDefault()` under `$('.artir , .azalt').on('click' , function () {`. 
Of course, you have to pass event like `$('.artir , .azalt').on('click' , function (event) {`)

**Please, Share your Laravel code** - maybe there is something not working or you have bug inside **routes**

PS: You don't need to pass new quantity inside the `data-adet`, but you can pass e.g. `data-operation="plus"` and `data-operation="minus"`.

Comment: Route::group(['prefix' => 'sepet'], function () {
    Route::patch('/guncelle/{rowid}', 'SepetController@guncelle')->name('sepet.guncelle');
});